# Is it possible to use Anaconda packages as dependencies for Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Google Cloud Function using the Python Runtime and I need to include some dependencies which are not available with `pip`. As described in the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python), it should be possible to package local dependencies, however, in my case, I would like to use all the packages of a local Anaconda environment and upload them with the function. Is there a way to do so?

Or alternatively, is there a way to specify Anaconda packages in the `requirements.txt` file instead of using `pip`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible, Cloud Functions only supports installing from PyPI via `pip`.

You may be interested in using [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) instead, which will allow you to define your own runtime, and thus install Anaconda packages via `conda`.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this through the requirements.txt file. As [each Cloud Function has its own file](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#structuring_source_code), you can specify different dependencies on each one.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449313/google-cloud-function-python-3-7-requirements-txt-makes-deploy-fail) to a similar question:

This is an example of a bunch of dependencies in a requirements.txt

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
Flask==1.0.2
dill>=0.2.8
numpy>=1.15.0
requests>=2.20.0
six==1.12.0
spacy>=2.1.0
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
torchtext>=0.3.1
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer as Anaconda package does not necessarily have a .whl file. For instance, how would you include this package (https://anaconda.org/CadQuery/pythonocc-core/files) in the requirements.txt file? My guess is that if you just copy the download link of the .tar.bz2 it would not work.

Comment: The proper tool is pip: "You can use the 'pip install' command with the '-t DIRECTORY' flag to copy private dependencies into a local directory before deploying your app". In the documentation you shared are the steps to follow.
About your guessing you are right. It does not work if that line is added.