# Is there a `conda` equivalent to `pip install -t`

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, google-cloud-functions, conda

I have private packages in a custom conda channel. I would like to use the dependencies with a Google Cloud Function. The [Google Cloud Function documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies) says to install your private dependencies using `pip install -t`.

Is there a `conda install` equivalent option to `-t`? I have not been able to find one with my searching. Is there another or better way to install private conda packages in Google Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not possible per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431462/is-it-possible-to-use-anaconda-packages-as-dependencies-for-google-cloud-functio).

[pip install -t](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options) specifies a directory where to install the dependencies, Possibly the conda counterpart would be [-p](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html)

Comment: I have tried -p, but that just lets you install to a specific conda environment at the specified path. I am also beginning to believe this is not possible.