# How are packages for the GCF obtained?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

My question is with regard to the packages required for Cloud Functions. My GCF requires fastai which I have already included in the `requirements.txt`. In `main.py`, I have included `import fastai`. And I do not have fastai installed in my system. Since its a GCF, when the function is deployed shouldn't it read the `requirements.txt` and get the required packages? Why does it throw an error saying the package is not installed locally.

**Updated:**

I have updated the packages in the script in the below manner.

`main.py`:

```
from fastai.vision import load_learner, Path
```

`requirements.txt:`

```
 fastai>=1.0
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "entryscript.py", line 3, in <module>
from main import pdfGenerate
File "/home/xxxx/patch_python/local_test_scripts/patchQuick/pdfGenerate/main.py", line 13, in <module>
from fastai.vision import load_learner, Path
File "/home/xxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/vision/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .. import basics
File "/home/xxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/basics.py", line 1, in <module>
from .basic_train import *
File "/home/xxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/basic_train.py", line 2, in <module>
from .torch_core import *
File "/home/xxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/torch_core.py", line 2, in <module>
from .imports.torch import *
File "/home/xxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/imports/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .torch import *
File "/home/xxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/imports/torch.py", line 1, in <module>
import torch, torch.nn.functional as F
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.nn.functional'
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal piece of code to reproduce your case?

Comment: Hi, please include the _exact error_ you're getting when deploying.

Comment: Looks like _fastai_ is trying to import yet another dependency, which cannot be found. Please have a look at [Installing PyTorch in your requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449313/google-cloud-function-python-3-7-requirements-txt-makes-deploy-fail) for more information. Also, this is how [dependencies work in Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python).

Comment: Note that _PyTorch v1_ and _Python 3.6_ are the minimal version requirements for _fastai_ as shown here: https://github.com/fastai/fastai#installation