# Google Cloud Function Build timeout - all requirements have been loaded

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, pytorch, cloud, requirements.txt

I have the following code on my cloud function -

```
import os
import numpy as np
import requests
 
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
import math
from torch.nn import BCEWithLogitsLoss
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
from transformers import AdamW, XLNetTokenizer, XLNetModel, XLNetLMHeadModel, XLNetConfig
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 
def polarization(request):
 
   MODEL_URL = 'https://polarization.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/classifier_state_dict.pt'
   print(MODEL_URL)
   r = requests.get(MODEL_URL)
   print(r)

   #Cloud function vm is a read only s/m. The only writable place is the tmp folder
   file = open("/tmp/model.pth", "wb")
   file.write(r.content)
   file.close()
  
   print("Wrote to the tmp file")
   # State dict requires model object
   model = XLNetForPolarizationClassification(num_labels=1)
   model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/tmp/model.pth'))
 
   # Tokenize the embedded article
   embeddedArticle = request["embeddedArticle"]
   tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', do_lower_case=True)
   textIds = tokenize_inputs(embeddedArticle, tokenizer, num_embeddings=250)
 
   # Generate the attention masks and padding
   masks = create_attn_masks(textIds)
   article = pd.DataFrame()
   article["features"] = textIds.tolist()
   article["masks"] = masks
 
   # Call generate_predictions
   pred = generate_predictions(model, article, 1)
 
   return pred
  
 
## Extracting parameter and returning prediction
def generate_predictions(model, df, num_labels, device="cpu"):
 
   model.eval()
          
   X = df_subset["features"].values.tolist()
   masks = df_subset["masks"].values.tolist()
 
   X = torch.tensor(X)
   masks = torch.tensor(masks, dtype=torch.long)
   with torch.no_grad():
       # Run the model with the input_ids and attention_masks separately
       logits = model(input_ids=X, attention_mask=masks)
       # Get the logits for each class
       logits = logits.sigmoid().detach().cpu().numpy()
          
   return round(logits)
 
 
class XLNetForPolarizationClassification(torch.nn.Module):
 
   def __init__(self, num_labels=2):
       super(XLNetForPolarizationClassification, self).__init__()
       self.num_labels = num_labels
       self.xlnet = XLNetModel.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased')
       self.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 1)
       torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.classifier.weight)
 
   def forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=None, labels=None):
 
       last_hidden_state = self.xlnet(input_ids=input_ids,
                                       attention_mask=attention_mask,
                                       token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
 
       mean_last_hidden_state = self.pool_hidden_state(last_hidden_state)
       logits = self.classifier(mean_last_hidden_state)
 
       # If you know the labels, compute the loss otherwise
       if labels is not None:
           loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
           loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1, self.num_labels))
           return loss
       else:
           return logits
      
   def pool_hidden_state(self, last_hidden_state):
       last_hidden_state = last_hidden_state[0]
       mean_last_hidden_state = torch.mean(last_hidden_state, 1)
       return mean_last_hidden_state
 
def create_attn_masks(input_ids):
 """
 This will set a 1 or 0 based on if it is a mask or an actual input it for the word
 """
 attention_masks = []
 
 for seq in input_ids:
   seq_mask = [float(i>0) for i in seq]
   attention_masks.append(seq_mask)
 return attention_masks
 
 
def tokenize_inputs(text, tokenizer, num_embeddings=250):
 
   # tokenize the text, then truncate sequence to the desired length minus 2 for
   # the 2 special characters
   tokenized_texts = list(map(lambda t: tokenizer.tokenize(t)[:num_embeddings-2], text))
 
   # convert tokenized text into numeric ids for the appropriate LM
   input_ids = [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x) for x in tokenized_texts]
 
   # append special token "<s>" and </s> to end of sentence
   input_ids = [tokenizer.build_inputs_with_special_tokens(x) for x in input_ids]
 
   # pad sequences
   input_ids = pad_sequences(input_ids, maxlen=num_embeddings, dtype="long", truncating="post", padding="post")
   return input_ids
```

and requirements.txt

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
filelock==3.0.12
future==0.18.2
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.10
joblib==0.16.0
Keras==2.4.3
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib==3.3.0
numpy==1.19.1
packaging==20.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2020.7.14
requests==2.24.0
sacremoses==0.0.43
scipy==1.5.2
sentencepiece==0.1.91
six==1.15.0
tokenizers==0.8.1rc1
torch==1.6.0
tqdm==4.48.2
transformers==3.0.2
urllib3==1.25.10
```

However when I deploy, it gives me build timed out. The logs don't show any errors and show that each of the dependencies in the requirements.txt file have built.  The first print statement doesn't get logged either. I don't see what part of the model/ requirements is causing the time out issue.
Here's a screenshot of the logs - there are no errors all the logs are info until theres a Conext deadline exceeded statement. I can't share the actual logs without giving access to the function I believe.  I've set the timeout to 9 minutes (540 seconds)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wogiz.png)

Comment: Have you checked the Cloud Storage bucket that is created for logging of Cloud Build? In case you don't, please, check more information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs). In case you have, could you please provide any log information available there? It can be the timed out message and any other information, as without any stack trace, it's hard to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: How long take your deployment ?

Comment: I'm not seeing an HTTP or Background function in your example (either `def function_name(request)` or `def function_name(data, context)`, is it missing?

Comment: great i did change the function polarization to take in a dictionary with request[embeddedArticle] instead however it still times out

Comment: it takes 9 minutes, also added a screenshot of the logs, thanks @gso_gabriel

Comment: Hi @a.sankar I would recommend you to reach out the [Google's 1:1 Support](https://cloud.google.com/support), so they can check a deeper look at your case, to confirm if it's not environment related, since you are not facing any errors.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the `torch` import, as this causes you to import the PyTorch lib that contains CUDA and hence requires a GPU, which isn't available on Cloud Functions.

Instead, you can use a direct link to the cpu only version in your requirements.txt, like this:

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
filelock==3.0.12
future==0.18.2
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.10
joblib==0.16.0
Keras==2.4.3
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib==3.3.0
numpy==1.19.1
packaging==20.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2020.7.14
requests==2.24.0
sacremoses==0.0.43
scipy==1.5.2
sentencepiece==0.1.91
six==1.15.0
tokenizers==0.8.1rc1
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
tqdm==4.48.2
transformers==3.0.2
urllib3==1.25.10
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449313/google-cloud-function-python-3-7-requirements-txt-makes-deploy-fail) about how to select a different PyTorch version.