# Google Cloud Function Gen 1 Deployment Failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lambda, pytorch, google-cloud-functions, stateless

This is mostly for the community, because it took me quite a while to figure out.

I have a python 3.9 environment stateless Google Cloud Function using pytorch.  The initial deployment and function creation has no errors/issues.  `Requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
torch==1.10.2
```

However, when I edit even the smallest, innocuous change and save, the deployment fails with the error:

```
Build failed:
Collecting torch==1.10.2; Error ID: c84b3231
```

How do you redeploy with pytorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still do not know the reason why installing pytorch on redeploy fails, but this is how I got Google Cloud Function to consistently redeploy without fail.  I directly input the specific version of PyTorch link: linux, cpu-based, version.

1. Go to the latest versions of PyTorch: [PyTorch Latest Releases](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html).
2. Search for the desired version (currently, the latest is 1.10.2).  I chose `torch-1.10.2%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl`.
3. Copy link and paste in `requirements.txt` by replacing `torch==1.10.2`.

If anybody knows why Google Cloud Function Gen 1 rejects redeployment with the conventional distribution of torch, feel free to edit.

Hope this saves someone time.

Comment: I think you may be falling foul of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449313/google-cloud-function-python-3-7-requirements-txt-makes-deploy-fail

Comment: @Kolban I saw the post but I don't understand why CUDA/GPU-expectation would allow initial cloud function creation to succeed (function runs as expected), while an update fails.  It almost makes me think it's a PIP-related issue, perhaps in the wheels in the updated/cached build environment or the pypi repo declaration.  Do you have any idea why it would cause this behavior of initial success, update fail?

Comment: I would suggest that this is likely worthy of raising a support ticket with Google.  In the original post, you showed a snippet of an error.  I think the best bet would be to "track that backwards".  Since the error is occurring in GCP Cloud, hopefully there are more logs that can be examined in Cloud Logging.  If nothing else, a minimal sample app that reproduces the error would be particularly useful.

Comment: Will try to take some time soon.  FWIW the Gen 2 preview does not have the same issue, though it has other shortcomings.  Both generations of GCF seem to have custom header propagation issues beyond those explained and excluded in documentation.